# Symfony2, unable to display result array in twig template

Tags: php, arrays, symfony, doctrine-orm, twig

I am new to symfony, I am trying to display an array of result into twig template. here is the issue..

Here's My entity

```php
<?php

namespace XYZ\FirstBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Shifts
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="XYZ\FirstBundle\Repository\ShiftRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="shifts")
 */
class Shifts
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="date", type="date")
     */
    private $date;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="site_name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $site_name;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="location", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $location;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="start_time", type="time")
     */
    private $startTime;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="end_time", type="time")
     */
    private $endTime;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set date
     *
     * @param \DateTime $date
     * @return Shifts
     */
    public function setDate($date)
    {
        $this->date = $date;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get date
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getDate()
    {
        return $this->date;
    }

    /**
     * Set site_name
     *
     * @param string $location
     * @return Shifts
     */
    public function setSitename($site_name)
    {
        $this->site_name = $site_name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get site_name
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getSitename()
    {
        return $this->site_name;
    }

    /**
     * Set location
     *
     * @param string $location
     * @return Shifts
     */
    public function setLocation($location)
    {
        $this->location = $location;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get location
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getLocation()
    {
        return $this->location;
    }

    /**
     * Set startTime
     *
     * @param \DateTime $startTime
     * @return Shifts
     */
    public function setStartTime($startTime)
    {
        $this->startTime = $startTime;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get startTime
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getStartTime()
    {
        return $this->startTime;
    }

    /**
     * Set endTime
     *
     * @param \DateTime $endTime
     * @return Shifts
     */
    public function setEndTime($endTime)
    {
        $this->endTime = $endTime;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get endTime
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getEndTime()
    {
        return $this->endTime;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return string String representation of this class
     */
    public function __toString()
    {

        return (string) $this->site_name;
        return (string) $this->location;
        return (string) $this->startTime;
        return (string) $this->endTime;


    }
}
```

Controller

```php
 public function showShiftAction() 
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $shift =array();
        $shift = $em->getRepository('XYZFirstBundle:Shifts')
         ->findAll();

         var_dump($shift);

        return $this->render('XYZFirstBundle:Default:allshifts.html.twig', array(
                'shift' => $shift
            ));
    }
```

Repository

```php
<?php

namespace XYZ\FirstBundle\Repository;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class ShiftRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function showAllShifts()
    {
        return $this->getEntityManager()
            ->createQuery (
                'SELECT Shifts FROM XYZFirstBundle:Shifts Shifts'
                )
            ->getResult();
    }
}
```

Now when I use the following in the template..

```html
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}RMS-Roster{% endblock %}


 {% block pageContent %}

    <h2>Create Roster</h2>   
                        <h5>These are all your shifts</h5> <br>
                        {{ shift.date }}
                        {{ shift.site_name }}
                        {{ shift.location }}
                        {{ shift.startTime }}
                        {{ shift.endTime }}

 {% endblock %}
```

I get this error -
Key "date" for array with keys "0, 1, 2, 3" does not exist in ATTERACFirstBundle:Default:allshifts.html.twig at line 10

but on `var_dump()` I am getting the entire array. and when i use this

```html
{% block pageContent %}

    <h2>Create Roster</h2>   
                        <h5>These are all your shifts</h5> <br>
                        {{ shift.0 }}
                        {{ shift.1 }}
                        {{ shift.2 }}
                        {{ shift.3 }}

 {% endblock %}
```

I am getting the only the site_name results.

**These are all your shifts

QUT Gardens point QUT kelvin grove milton station Melbourne**

I am not sure where i am going wrong. looking forward for insights.
Thanks in advance.
Cheers

Comment: Your __toString method will only return site_name so if you want to display first element od shift it wille be site_name. If you want more informatiob chain them with dots like

Answer (score 2):

```
{% for shiftObject in shift %} {{ shiftObject.example }} {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Damn.. thanks.. am such a noob.. lol
Use "for" loop.. so simple.